# Rails: How to send the contents of an <option> tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I know that when using Rails there is a naming convention for html forms that allows input values to be automatically sent as params to the controller upon form submit. For example, when you submit a `<input id="user_name" name="user[name]"/>` to the controller, you can then capture the value of that input with `params[:user][:name]`.

I also know that if I submit a select tag such as:

```
<select name="user[car]">
  <option value="1" selected>Volvo</option>
  <option value="2">Saab</option>
  <option value="3">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="4">Audi</option>
</select>
```

I can capture the value `1` with `params[:user][:car]` in the controller.

But what can I do if I have the same select tag and I want to send **both** the ID of the car *and* the name of the car? Is there a way to do that without creating an extra text field that receives the car name on the `change` event of the select tag?

Comment: Why would you need to do this? The controller should have an array that relates the values to the names.

Comment: If not, you could put them into the values, `value="1 Volvo"`.

Comment: The controller in this case doesn't keep an array doing that. I want to do this in order to prevent an unnecessary database query for the name of the car. The action in question uses the name of the car simply for logging purposes.

Comment: Then do my second suggestion. But both the ID and name in the value, and split it up in the controller.